# Is there any way for Validating cell value in excel (vsto)

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, vsto

Suppose i have some value in excel cell,its type may be anything **date,numeric or string**
and i want that cell to be **validated against its type**...
Is there any way of doing this ?
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you mean that you have contents in a cell, which could be either a date, a double, or a plain string, and that you want to assert what corresponding .NET type it is. I believe there is no direct way of doing this. One approach would be to retrieve the Value2 in the cell, and try to cast it to each of these types, starting from the most restrictive one, until the cast works - i.e. DateTime (DateTime.FromOADate), then double (Convert.ToDouble), then string - and then apply the validation rule that applies to the particular type you found.
I am not quite sure what you mean by validation, though, and what that would buy you. Once you know the type of the content, what would you do with it?

Comment: Suppose user enter wrong date value in cell and i want to prompt user about it as soon as he enters the date... i tried sheetchange event but since i used copy cell most offen the shhet change event fires at that time and so the validation which is not feasible to me... thanks for u r response :)

Comment: You may be able to do what you want, but it depends on how structured the sheet is - and it takes quite a bit of work. Suppose you have a sheet where you know that column C should contain dates; then you can use the content changed event for the sheet, check whether the changed range contains cells in column C, and exercise the appropriate validation.

Comment: Nice explanation Mathias. This is essentially the only way to begin cell validation since you first need to seperate Value2 into either a string, double, OLEDate or Bool.

Answer (score 1):

I use Excel's data validation technique in a VSTO application myself. It obviously isn't VSTO but it works well enough. There are some drawbacks like you can't have multiple validations on the same cell (i.e. you have to know what your validating for)

Comment: Validations and Format can be used together ,Right ? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use the excel's functionality !!!
no need of any coding for that !!

instead of hard work go for the smart work ...

In excel, 
Go to the cell where you want the validation to come

**Menu ->> Data --> validation**

Here you can  directly use the various  excel validation terms.
Which you can refer [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211485) or..

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211485

Thanx
Regards.

Comment: if u can do it very easily and perfectly through the existing  platform  like EXCEL ..why are u opting the tougher way to do that !!! Decision is yours !!! :-)

Comment: hey,i am aware of the default validation of excel but i want to know is ther any methode to do it through code? i am just tring to explore the things....    :)